# how to make a string empty in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm using C here.

```
char a[4], b = 'A';
int k = 0, count = 0;
while true {
    if count == 26
        break;
    if k == 4 {
        k = 0;
        count++;
        b++;
        //I want the solution code here.
        printf("%s", a);
    }
    a[k] = b;
    k++;
}
```

I need to know that, If a string in C got assigned completely, is it possible to empty that string again? I can show you my desired output.

> AAAABBBBCCCC........ZZZZ

Please help me.

Comment: Please copy/paste the original code again. Somehow you managed to remove all parenthesis from the code.

Comment: not required to set it empty. Just set the a[0]='\0'. Since the string is never going to be 0. Because not initialized arrays contains not defined values (probably not '\0').

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways come to mind. Given that strings in C are usually terminated by an **ASCII** zero, the easiest would be to set the **first byte to zero**.

```
a[0] = '\0';
```

Now this **doesn't erase all the characters in the string**, but since the first character is now a termination character the string looks empty to your program.

If you want to **erase all the characters** in the string then you need to use a **loop**.

**OR**

Another way might be to use **memset()** to set the whole string to zeros.

```
memset(a, 0, strlen(a));
```

but this will only work for **zeroing up to the first NULL character**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
a[0] = '\0';
```

or

```
strcpy(a, "");
```

But your code seem to have a general problem with string termination.

In C a string is terminated (i.e. it ends) with the character `'\0'` and you code fails to add that termination. You could do:

```
    a[k] = b;
    a[k+1] = '\0';
```

or

```
   if k == 4 {
       a[k] = '\0';
```

If you call `printf` and the string isn't terminates, you program may crash.

Also notice that `char a[4];` should be `char a[5];` as you need to store things like `"AAAA\0"`, i.e. 5 characters because you need the 4 `A` plus a termination.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it should suffice to do:

```
a[0] = '\0';
```

This sets the first char in the string to be the null terminating character, such that when you print the string, it prints an empty string.

You should also assign the null terminating character to after the effective last character:

```
a[0] = 'a';
a[1] = 'b';
a[2] = '\0';
printf("%s", a); //print "ab"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are building 4 letters strings, so you need an array of size 5.
A string must be ended with `\0`, if not it is not a string, see standard:

> 7.1.1 Definitions of terms
>
> 1 A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

You don't need to reset the string as you only print it when it will be correctly filled, you just have to fill it while looping as you did it.

```
char a[5], b = 'A';
int k = 0, count = 0;
a[5] = '\0'; // mark end of string
while true {
    if (count == 26)
        break;
    if (k == 4) {
        k = 0;
        count++;
        b++;
        printf("%s", a);
    }
    a[k] = b;
    k++;
}
```