# token recognition shell quote empty

Tags: c, token, lexer

I'm doing a shell from scratch. If I store all tokens in an array `char**`, what I supposed to put in a string of array `char**` when quote is empty?

Example:

```
input>echo "" "" "" | cat -e
output>(space)(space)(space)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mimicking POSIX shells then each `""` would tokenize to an empty string. The pipeline as a whole should tokenize to:

```
char *tokens[] = {"echo", "", "", "", "|", "cat", "-e"};
```

Comment: Is it the only way ? It will be easier for me to have no quote in my storage

Comment: There are no quotes here. This is C syntax. The array contains `echo` (strlen 4), `<empty string>` (strlen 0), etc.

Comment: Ok, in the <empty string> what do you store ? I guess not a 0 cause it will make some trouble to iterate in the *token[]

Comment: An [empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285483/how-to-make-a-string-empty-in-c). You can get an empty string from `strcpy(str, "");` or `str[0] = '\0';` or `*str = '\0';` or `char str[] = "";` or `const char *str = ""`.